# DNS Error - Server cannot be found

Tags: domain-name-system

when I browse my web site this error appeared 
DNS Error - Server cannot be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try a dnsflush, from the command line:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Try using different DNS servers like :
OpenDNS: **208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220** or 
Google FreeDNS service: **8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4** 

If you really want to push it just run your own DNS servers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software

And also double check the nameservers that handle your domain (the website):

```
dig <yourdomain> (is dig ported to windows?)
```

Or try : http://network-tools.com/

Comment: where i can find ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: start->run->cmd
and just type: ipconfig /flushdns and press enter :)

Comment: Thank you more I Solved My problem but I want to know real reason of what happened

Comment: and How can i Do 
dig <yourdomain> (is dig ported to windows?)

Comment: dig would be available on a linux system and you can find it http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/ or http://serghei.org/windows/dig/ for windows

Comment: Dig is included in the BIND nameserver package, developed and distributed by the Internet Systems Consortium (ISC.)  Binary packages for Windows are available from http://www.isc.org/downloads/current (and for dig it doesn't really matter which server version you choose.)  The Windows installer has an option for tools only, which you should choose if you don't want to install the server on your Windows workstation.